# How do I find where an environmental variable got set?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, command-line, environment-variables

I installed a program to try it out, and decided I didn't like it so I moved the app to the trash.

Today, in my shell, I noticed that there are a couple of PROGRAMNAME_BLAHBLAH environmental variables set.  I'd like to remove those, too.

I don't even have a .bashrc or .bash_login, so I grepped every file I could think of (~/.* ~/Library/* /Library/* /etc/*).  The only place these variables turned up was a file ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist, so I removed it from there (Xcode can edit binary plists), but new shells still have these variables set.

What other files does Mac OS X 10.7's terminal/bash run on startup?  How might these variables get set?

Or is it something funny like "need to reboot after editing environment.plist"?

Comment: Can you list some specific examples of env variables you want to get rid of? Might make it easier to identify potential sources. And after changing environment.plist you need at least to logout/login again.

Comment: patrix: Log out, as in "Apple Menu -> Log Out" (as opposed to logging out of the shell)?

Comment: Yes, as in "Apple Menu -> Log Out".

Comment: See also [How to determine where an environment variable came from](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from) (which isn't Mac-specific)

Comment: Is there anything we can add to daniel's answer to get your problem sorted out?

Answer (score 3):

`~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` is read at session start. If you want your change to it to be tested immediatly you have to restart your session.
A restart of the system is useless.
You can edit this environment initialisation file with:

```
plutil -convert xml1 environment.plist
vi environment.plist
```

I advise you to simply recover it to its version prior to your software
installation.

Other hint, check all the files which were modified on the date
of installation of your unwanted software.
If you installed your software 15 days ago, you can perform this with:

```
find / -mtime -16 -mtime +14 -ls
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154971/3358)—which is not macOS-specific but probably much more likely to be relevant—solved the problem for me.

If you use `zsh`, this will give you a ton of output to search through:

```
zsh -xl
```

If `bash` is your thing

```
PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE> ' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xl 7>&2
```

See the original answer for more details.

Comment: You linked a question with ***9 answers!***  Which one of these answers worked for you?  Please post the relevant portions here rather than take the reader off site (even if another StackExchange community) to get the answer.